# Retrieve private service endpoints using the ibmcloud cli

Tags: ibm-cloud

Most services on the IBM Cloud catalog now support "private endpoints" as described at https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/account?topic=account-service-endpoints-overview

I'm writing some automation for our application and I'd like to obtain the private endpoint for my database from a simple bash script.
I found that I can create a service key and invoke `ibmcloud resource service-key (NAME | ID)` to list the contents of that key (which includes the service's public endpoint).
Unfortunately, I can't seem to find any command for listing the corresponding private endpoint.

In this particular case I am using the `databases-for-postgresql` service, but I was hoping for a general way to do this that will work across service types.
I can get the private endpoint information from the UI, so I know the service instance has one.

If I can't get the private endpoint from an existing command, can I piggy-back on the cli's session to invoke a curl command without messing with IAM?
For example, to invoke the curl command mentioned at the bottom of https://www.ibm.com/cloud/blog/introducing-private-service-endpoints-in-ibm-cloud-databases

```
curl -sS -XPOST "https://api.us-south.databases.cloud.ibm.com/v4/ibm/deployments/<deployment CRN/users/admin/connections/private" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer <IBM API TOKEN>"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IBM Cloud CLI Cloud Databases plug-in provides this capability. Details about the `deployment-connections` command can be found here: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/databases-cli-plugin?topic=databases-cli-plugin-cdb-reference#connections

The syntax is roughly: `ibmcloud cdb deployment-connections [the-database] -e private`

If you have not already installed this plug-in, you can do so with this command: `ibmcloud plugin install cdb`

Comment: Thanks, I was able to use the `--json` option with this and pull out the field via `jq -r '.connection.postgres.hosts[0].hostname'`.
I also found that, if the service is created with *only* a private service endpoint, that in that case the service-key mechanism *does* return that endpoint.